# How do I create a wheel from a manually altered Python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a Python package I installed locally, `thrift-sasl`, but because of Python 3 compatibility issues I had to change the source code slightly, so I now have a "custom" version of `thrift-sasl`.

I work with conda environments, and if I create a new one where I want to use `thrift-sasl` I don't want to have to make that manual change each time.

Is a wheel the right way to "repackage" this library and if so, how do I do it? The wheel documentation doesn't obviously address this use case so I'm unsure.

Comment: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`?

Comment: I've seen that command a few times when looking for an answer. What is setup.py in this case and where would this command be run? There's no setup.py inside the thrift-sasl site-packages folder for example...

Comment: [This is docs for Python packaging](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html) that explains `setup.py` et al. And `thrift-sasl` has [setup.py](https://github.com/cloudera/thrift_sasl/blob/master/setup.py). To run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` you need [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) package.

Comment: Thanks, what wasn't clear was that I had to create my own setup.py that just installs the library (with amended source files).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I figured it out. I had to create my own setup.py (outside the thrift-sasl folder) with just the following in it:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="thrift-sasl", version="0.2.1dev", packages=["thrift_sasl"])
```

where `version` is something you can make up and `thrift_sasl` is the name of the folder that contains the source files.

I could then run

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

which creates a `dist` folder, in which is the correct wheel, which can be installed with:

```
pip install path_to_wheel.whl
```